# Symfony Entity index list with CRUD - need modal for edit

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-modal, crud

I’ve created a CRUD page in Symfony. (symfony 5/bootstrap 4)
I now have an index page with data with “show, edit” links behind every row like this:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Topic</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>DueDate</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.topic }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.dueDate ? item.dueDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') : '' }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.duration }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.status ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('item_show', {'id': item.id}) }}">show</a>
                <a href="{{ path('item_edit', {'id': item.id}) }}">edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">no records found</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the edit link goes to another page, but i want to edit this in a modal, for example something like this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should i do this? Or maybe a good tutorial somewhere?

Comment: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/stimulus/modal-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use ajax
instead of this `<a href="{{ path('item_edit', {'id': item.id}) }}">edit</a>`

u can do something like that :

```
<button type="button" onclick="Edit('{{ item.id}}')" class="btn-edit dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">   edit </button>
```

then creat function ajax called Edit ( this is an example for update just label so I take value of input and put it in a variable called label to passed as parameter in my function edit)

function Edit(id) {

```
    $('button#editBtn').on('click', function () {
        var label = $('input#label').val()
        $.ajax({
            method: "PATCH",
            url: "/api/item/edit/" + id ,
            data: JSON.stringify({label: label}),
            
        }).done(function (res) {
            

        }).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)
        })
    })
}
```

of course u need to create function Edit in the controller